# Redirect stdout to file and then stop doing, from windows service

Tags: c#, c++, windows, stdout

I'm trying out this code in my application, which I've taken from microsoft documentation

```
#include <io.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  

int main( void )  
{  
   int old;  
   FILE *DataFile;  

   old = _dup( 1 );   // "old" now refers to "stdout"   
                      // Note:  file descriptor 1 == "stdout"   
   if( old == -1 )  
   {  
      perror( "_dup( 1 ) failure" );  
      exit( 1 );  
   }  
   _write( old, "This goes to stdout first\n", 26 );  
   if( fopen_s( &DataFile, "data", "w" ) != 0 )  
   {  
      puts( "Can't open file 'data'\n" );  
      exit( 1 );  
   }  

   // stdout now refers to file "data"   
   if( -1 == _dup2( _fileno( DataFile ), 1 ) )  
   {  
      perror( "Can't _dup2 stdout" );  
      exit( 1 );  
   }  
   puts( "This goes to file 'data'\n" );  

   // Flush stdout stream buffer so it goes to correct file   
   fflush( stdout );  
   fclose( DataFile );  

   // Restore original stdout   
   _dup2( old, 1 );  
   puts( "This goes to stdout\n" );  
   puts( "The file 'data' contains:" );  
   _flushall();  
   system( "type data" );  
}
```

In debug seems to be working fine, as I'm launching the service from command line, and stdout is being redirected to either the console or to the output file

But in release mode, when starting the services from services.msc, it seems that old is equal to -1, so nothing work ..

My whole work is just to redirect stdout to the file, and then at some point stop it.
Whereas if I just open the file and then close it, when done, it keeps crashing

It's a mixed up application C++ and C#

Thank you!

Comment: What is stdout in the context of a service? It has no output stream context, surely? Why don't you instead write your program with a flexible logging aparatus?

Comment: You say C++ but the code you’ve shown looks like C, not C++.